# Limiting google chrome fullscreen to window size

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Context;
I had the issue of needing to play youtube videos in fullscreen, but still needing access to the my tabs. So I needed a way to limit the view to the sites viewing window.

Question;
Is there a way to limit the fullscreen view of a video to the  --window-size of it?
Or a way to intercept a fullscreen request and denying it?
So it is possible on a desktop and mobile limit the fullscreen view

Comment: You can intercept the click on the fullscreen button element using standard DOM event listeners (probably in *useCapture* mode), then just resize the player to the window size, and change its z-index.